# Creating and using .NET Core class library in ASP.NET project

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I started a new ASP.NET Core WebApi project from Visual Studio. Project initialized and started without problem.

Now I want to add a .NET Core class library to contain logic separated from the app. So I right-clicked the `src` folder, chose `Add -> New Project` and chose `Class LOibrary (.NET Core)`.

In my class library I created a new middleware:

```
namespace MyClassLib
{
    public class MyMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```

And created extension method for it:

```
namespace MyClassLib
{
    public static class MyMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}
```

So far nothing fancy.

In my web API I added a reference to that project:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "MyClassLib": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

But when I try to use my new class library in my WebApi `startup` class it doesn't seem to recognize it - showing the `using MyClassLib` in red (error) and not allowing me to use any of the classes inside it.

What am I missing here? previous to .NET Core this is something I used to do all the time...

**EDIT**

Strange, but if I disable ReSharper than everything works. If I re-enable ReSharper than it shows errors again but still compiles. I've seen posts on GitHub from people who encountered this problem on RC1 - but it was mentioned that it was fixed. Anyone knows how I can continue working with ReSharper and .NET Core?

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be that there's an [existing package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MyClassLib) in the NuGet gallery called `MyClassLib` that has a version [1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MyClassLib/1.0.0), so NuGet is probably pulling that down and referencing that.

In order to instruct the project system to use the local project, instead of a published package, try doing

```
"MyClassLib": { "target": "project" }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Please see my edit in original post regarding ReSharper

Comment: I'd check out the ReSharper EAP program. I'm not sure if .NET Core is fully supported yet, but they've done tons of bugfixes in the [2016.2 release](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/05/27/resharper-ultimate-2016-2-eap-kicks-off/).

Comment: I was having similar issues with ReSharper and am currently on the EAP release.  Still a little iffy at times with references, but, improved overall.